# Getting msc, imsi and cell id using asterisk

Tags: asterisk, gsm

Is it possible to use asterisk to get the cell id of a mobile phone? I want to get the cell id of a phone without the necessity to install extra software on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "cell id", you mean the mobile phone number, then that's available in the CALLERID variable. See:  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+callerid

Note however, that caller ID can be spoofed, and should not be the basis for any access control.

If by "cell id", you mean the mobile [ESN/IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Serial_Number):  no, that information is <strike>generally</strike> not available to PBX systems like Asterisk.

Comment: I meean the mobile esn/imei. What do you mean by "generally" not available? Is there a way to get this info, however?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do it for calls coming into Asterisk, w/o having software running on the phone.  I'll make my answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Cell id is the unique numeric value assigned to each Base Transceiver Station within Location Area which is also identified with Location Are Code and specific to mobile networks. Asterisk provides computer telephony interface for IVR and PBX applications through ISUP and SIP protocols those are not mobile network specific call control protocols. Unless otherwise it is not implemented as vendor specific parameter in IAM and INVITE messages , you would not receive cell id or location area code.